# Not able to generate .xcarchive file after updating Xcode version to 11.0

Tags: cordova, ionic3

**Ionic version:**
[x] **3.x**

**Current behavior:**
Only build is happening, no archive process

**Expected behavior:**
Should generate .xcarchive after build succeed

**Related code:**

```
cordova build ios --buildConfig build.json --noSign=true
```

**Ionic info:**

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 5.2.6 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms : ios 5.0.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.5.2, (and 12 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/Abhishek/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 1.9.4
   ios-sim           : 8.0.2
   NodeJS            : v10.12.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.9.0
   OS                : macOS Mojave
   Xcode             : Xcode 11.0 Build version 11A420a
```

Comment: Can you post console error while you running above command to build your archive?

Comment: @CodeChanger , console ends up without any error. 

this log is coming after build process completed:

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

And .xcarchive file is missing or not generating because i am not seeing any logs process related to archive or export after build.

Comment: ohh ok, so can you run above build command with --verbose? so at least we can get where the actual error is.

Comment: @CodeChanger sharing a GIT repo and try build from your side if possible, thanks

Comment: Managed to fix this issue.